# How to iterate over data that came from JsonConvert.DeserializeObject?

Tags: c#, .net, loops

I'm using a Azure function to create an excel file, but I'm having a little bit of difficult to iterate the input.

This is the input:

```
{
    "data": {
        "Header1": {
            "body": [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And I want get first the keys of the object inside the "data" and put it in the first top cells, but I'm having a little bit of difficult to iterate and get the keys from it. That's what I'm trying to do:

```
        Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(body as string);
        foreach (var item in data.data.Keys)
        {
            // For each iteration, go to the right. In this case, `i` doesn't exist.
            // Is there a way to do it then?
            Cells[0, i] = item; // Not item, the key of item.
        }
```

The Header1 is just an example, the key could be any word.

The Data class:

```
public class Data
{
    public dynamic data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you put your Data class?

Comment: Yes, give me one second

Comment: There it is @Haitam

Comment: The only thing in *that* JSON you can iterate is `body` there is only one of anything else.  This really is not any different than [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47961170/1070452) except the title

Comment: So, you are saying that it is impossible to iterate over the keys Header1, Header2, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a better structure, you'll have to ditch working with dynamic variables and write some classes, here is an example:

```
public class DataContainer
{

    public Dictionary<string, Header> Data { get; set; }

}

public class Header
{
    public int[] Body { get; set; }

}
```

All you have to do now is use it like this:

```
string json = "{\"data\":{\"Header1\":{\"body\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]}}}";
DataContainer data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataContainer>(json);
```

This will give you a DataContainer instance with the correct informations, you can iterate over it like this:

```
foreach (var kvp in data.Data)
{
    // kvp.Key holds the keys (Header1, etc...)
    // kvp.Value holds a Header instance
    // kvp.Value.body holds the integer array you have
}
```